# How to shift AGN x-ray spectrum to rest frame

Tags: astronomy, x-rays, redshift

I have limited information to shift a spectrum (in the x-ray 0.5-10 keV bandpass) at redshift z=2 to rest frame. I have a plot of normalized (photon) counts s$^{-1}$ keV$^{-1}$ by energy (keV), and so I have no information to compute the flux density. Is there a way to shift the spectrum I have to rest frame? Or do I really need luminosity distance, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The frequency is [related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift#Measurement.2C_characterization.2C_and_interpretation) to the redshift by $$\frac{\nu_{\rm obs}}{\nu_{\rm emit}} = \frac{1}{1+z}$$

Another useful [relation](https://casper.berkeley.edu/astrobaki/index.php/Specific_Intensity#Proof_that_Specific_Intensity_is_conserved_along_a_ray) is the fact that, for any redshift,

$$\frac{I_{\nu}}{\nu^3} = {\rm constant}$$

where $I_{\nu}$ is the [specific radiative intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_radiative_intensity).

The specific count rate (counts per area per time per energy interval) is proportional to $I_{\nu}/\nu$. (Do you see why?)

That should give you enough information to derive how the measured count rate changes with $z.$ Of course, to know the actual value, not just the function of $z$, you'd need to know the actual count rate measured, not just the normalized value.

Comment: This question is cross-posted in astronomy. I think it belongs _there_, not here in physics.SE.